# Why can't anyone else access my website in IIS on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, asp.net, iis-7

I've got an ASP.NET application that I have in IIS on my Windows 7 Ultimate machine.  I've tested it from that machine and it works fine.  This machine is in my home network, a simple peer-to-peer network.  The strange thing is that no one else in my network can access that website.  Why is that?  There are other Windows 7 machines here, and they're all in the same homegroup.  When I attempt to access the website on my machine from one of the other machines, it fails and that's it.

So, what's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing I would check is your firewall settings. If it works with the firewall disabled, then re-enable the firewall and open port 80 (for HTTP) for incoming connections. You may have to open other ports for other services like FTP.

Comment: I'm not sure if I've done the right thing of not, but I disabled my AV (which is VIPRE) and tried it from another machine on my P2P network.  It still timed out trying to connect.

Comment: A firewall is different from antivirus. A firewall prevents or allows certain types of connections to a PC. If you don't know what firewall you are running, then it's probably the Windows Firewall. Open Control Panel (Start > Control Panel) and find the Windows Firewall application. Disable it temporarily and test the connection. If that works, then enable it and add an exception for IIS.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Control Panel -> Windows Firewall - Click advanced settings, 
Rules for incoming traffic, in my case i had to enable World Wide Web services - (Incoming Traffic) 
NOTE: I found 2 "World Wide Web services - (Incoming Traffic)" you have to enable them both

Before this i also mapped port 80 on my router, but it started working after i enabled those firewall rules.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have done something truly dumb - like me - and overlooked the obvious?  Open IIS Manager.  Click the server in the left pane.  Click View Sites in the right pane.  Find your site in the middle pane and check the status.  If the status is off, right click and Manage Web Site -> Start.